# How do I count the number of occurrences of a character in a string using textboxes?

Tags: javascript, count

I want to count the number of times the single character, denoted by `letter`, occurs in `str`.

I have tried this code but I constantly receive back a value of just 1.

```
var x = document.getElementById('txt1').value;
var y = document.getElementById('txt2').value;

var letter = x;
var str = y;    

for (var i = count = 0; i < str.length; count +++(letter === str[i++]));
count;

alert(i);
```

Comment: It certainly doesn't do what you want, but I don't see how it's returning 1 unless the length of `str` is 1.

Comment: I love it: `+++/===` all these triple ops!

Comment: @minseong well `+++` is two operators (`++` and `+`)

Comment: @Pointy I know. It looks funny, that's all I'm saying.

Comment: It took me a minute or two to realize what that overall expression was doing (nothing other than incrementing `count` and `i` :)

Comment: I tried your code several times, and not once did it return 1.

Comment: [This already has an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27970424/how-do-i-count-the-number-of-occurrences-of-a-character-in-a-string-using-textbo/27971196#27971196)

Answer (score 1):

something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/swm53ran/96/

```
<input id="txt1" value="i"/>
<input id="txt2" value="This is my string"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var x =document.getElementById('txt1').value;
    var y = document.getElementById('txt2').value;

    var letter = x;
    var str = y;    
    var count = 0;

    var arrayX = str.split('');
    console.log(arrayX);    

    for (var i = 0; i < arrayX.length; i++) {
        if (arrayX[i] == letter) {
            count++;
        }   
    }

    alert(count);
</script>
```

Comment: Fun hack: replace the loop with `count = str.split(letter).length - 1`

Answer (score 1):

The current problem is this part of your for loop: `count +++(letter === str[i++])`, let's walk through what happens:

1. If `letter === str[i]`, add one (`true`) to count.
2. Add one to `i`.
3. **Count is incremented**.
4. Repeat unless `i >= str.length`.

As you can see, count *is always* incremented by at least 1, sometimes 2. `i` is also incremented in each repetition.

What you need is a for-loop that looks like:

```
for (var i = count = 0; i < str.length;  count += (str[i++] == letter));
```

```js
function getNumber(){
  var str = document.getElementById('txt1').value;
  var letter = document.getElementById('txt2').value;

  var count;
  for (var i = count = 0; i < str.length;  count += (str[i++] == letter));

  document.querySelector('p').innerText = count;
}
```

```html
str: <input type="text" id="txt1"><br>
letter: <input type="text" id="txt2"><br>
<button onclick="getNumber()">Get Result</button><br>
result: <p></p>
```

[Or full experience at this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/anykj3mf/)

Here ^^, count is only incremented if `letter == str[i]`, so if that condition is false, count remains unchanged.

---

Or, perhaps less succinctly, you can use a [regular expression (regex)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) to the same effect:

```
var regex = new RegExp(letter, 'g');
var count = (letter.length) ? str.match(regex).length : 0;
```

Comment: Can you please explain the FOR loop? I've little understanding of it!

Comment: @TusharShukla The for loop has three sections inside of the brackets: `for (A; B; C)`. Section A is used to initialise some variables. I set `i` and `count` to 0. Section B checks if the loop should keep going. If B is false, the loop stops. Above, I've said: `i < str.length`. This means that the loop will stop when `i` is no longer less than `str.length`. Section C is executed (run) every time the loop repeats. My Section C above adds 1 to count if `str[i]` is equal to `letter`. Then `i` is increased by 1.

Comment: Let's look at `count += (str[i++] == letter)`; `count += a` means `count = count + a`. In this case, `a` is `(str[i++] == letter)`, which is a comparison. Comparisons which are true (`10 == 9+1`) have the value 1 as well. So, if `(str[i++] == letter)` is true, `count` increases by 1. `str[i++]` means `str[i]`, but then adds 1 to `i` afterwards.

Comment: Perfect!! Thanks for explaining.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a basic implementation using regex instead of splitting or writing a loop.

```js
function go() {
  var letter = document.getElementById('txt1').value;
  var str = document.getElementById('txt2').value;
  var re = new RegExp(letter,"g");
  var count = (str.match(re || []).length);
  alert(count);
}
```

```html
<label for="txt1">Character</label>
<input type="text" id="txt1" maxlength="1" />
<br/>
<label for="txt2">String</label>
<input type="text" id="txt2" />
<input type="button" value="go" onclick="go()" />
```